# JQuery ui - date picker, disabling specific dates

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to disable specific dates using the JQuery Ui. However, I am having no luck, here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="development-bundle/themes/ui-lightness/jquery.ui.all.css">
<style type="text/css">
.ui-datepicker .preBooked_class { background:#111111; }
.ui-datepicker .preBooked_class span { color:#999999; }
</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="development-bundle/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
```

Instantiate datepicker object

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
    $( "#iDate" ).datepicker({

    dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
    beforeShowDay: checkAvailability
    });

    })
```

Get the dates to be disabled within the calendar

```
    var unavailableDates = ["9-3-2012","14-3-2012","15-3-2012"];

function unavailable(date) {
  dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
  if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
    return [true, ""];
  } else {
    return [false,"","Unavailable"];
  }
}

$('#iDate').datepicker({ beforeShowDay: unavailable });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="iDate">
</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't seem to be working, any idea how I can resolve this. cheers.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It looks like you're calling `datepicker` twice on one input. Its kind of hard to follow your code, but if you re-organize it and remove the second `datepicker` call, everything should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var unavailableDates = ["9-3-2012", "14-3-2012", "15-3-2012"];

    function unavailable(date) {
        dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
        if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
            return [true, ""];
        } else {
            return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
        }
    }

    $(function() {
        $("#iDate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
            beforeShowDay: unavailable
        });

    });
</script>
```

Check this article: [disable-dates-in-datepicker](https://dzone.com/articles/disable-dates-in-datepicker)

Comment: Works perfectly, a quick question andrew. How can I adapt this so that instead of the unavailable dates being hard coded within the array, the dates are retrieved from a database table. cheers.

Comment: @bobo2000: That depends on your server-side technology. But I would imagine you would embed the array of excluded dates on the page on page load instead of hard coding them in the JavaScript.

Comment: Using PHP. Will I need to query the db then populate the array with the result set?

Comment: @bobo2000: That sounds correct. I'm not very knowledgeable with PHP though. Sounds like a candidate for a new question `:)`

Comment: This worked but how can I do it without specifying the dates in the array , it say in need the next three days . Like if it comes to tomorrow it selects the following three like that

Answer (score 0):

Helpful answer..If you want to disable a perticular day, you can do as below:

```
          $scope.dateOptions = {
            beforeShowDay: unavailable
          };

          function unavailable(date) {
                if (date.getDay() === 0) {
                    return [true, ""];
                } else {
                    return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
                }
          }
```

the above will only enable Sunday and all other days will be disabled. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
var unavailableDates = ["23-09-2022", "24-09-2022", "25-09-2022"];
$('#res_date').datepicker({
  startDate: '-0m', // this for disable past days
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  todayHighlight:'TRUE',
  autoclose: true,
  datesDisabled: unavailableDates // for disable your specific days
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To flip the answer on its head for *available dates* you can now use the javascript `includes()` and return the bool value in an array.

```
var availableDates = ["5-6-2023", "6-6-2023", "7-6-2023"];

function available(date) {
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();

    return [availableDates.includes(dmy)];
}

$("#iDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
    beforeShowDay: available
});
```

The 2nd element in the array is a css class and the 3rd param is an optional tooltip (https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay)

Worth saying that as of 2023 Jquery UI is on the way out, but its still quite a nice toolset.