# jQuery UI datepicker show month when mindate is in the future

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

This is my code:

```
$('#dp').datepicker();
$('#dp').datepicker( "setDate", "05/01/2013" );
$('#dp').datepicker("option", "minDate", "07/01/2013" );
```

Currently when I open the date picker I see the month of July 2013 since this is the `minDate`, however I would like to see the month of May 2013 and see all the dates for that month disabled (since the minDate is July 2013).

Is it possible to `setDate` to a month prior to the `minDate`?

Comment: If specific dates need to be disabled, review this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742289/jquery-ui-date-picker-disabling-specific-dates and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400775/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-array-of-dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var d = $.datepicker.parseDate("mm/dd/yy", "07/01/2013");
$('#dp').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        return [date >= d, ''];
    }
});
$('#dp').datepicker("setDate", "05/01/2013");
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zPNeD/1/)**