# How can I use the jQuery Datepicker UI to dynamically pull a list of available times for the specific date selected?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datepicker

I want to be clear that I am not asking someone to write the code for me.  I want to learn how to do this myself.

What I am trying to accomplish is this:  I have a website where I need a user to be able to select a date and time for an appointment.  What I would like to be able to do is have the user select a date from the jQuery DatePicker UI and use that selected date to dynamically populate a list of available time slots that I can display to the user so they can choose a time based on the available time slots.  Similar to the way it's done on this page under step 3 - https://booking.maidsinblack.com/ .

I really want to learn this for myself, but I need a nudge in the right direction.  I can get the jQuery DatePicker working on the page without an issue, but I am learning PHP/MySQL.  What commands in PHP/MySQL will I need to send the chosen date from the calendar to PHP, use that to pull available times in MySQL, then send the related information back to the page for selection?

I really appreciate any help on this.  Ive been searching Google for the past two hours attempting to find examples of what I am trying to do with no luck.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742289/jquery-ui-date-picker-disabling-specific-dates

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but that code appears to be using javascript to block out certain dates on the calendar?

I will need the dates to be removed from the database as they are chosen.  That method seems to need me to define what isn't available.