# Disabling a specific day in jQuery-UI datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have the follow code to disable 22-02-2014, but don´t works...

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var day = date.getDay();
            return [(day == 0 || day == 6)];
            var array = ["22-02-14"]
            $('#input_2_5').datepicker({
beforeShowDay: function(date){
            var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
            return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
```

Form with datepicker is    [here](http://entrestaciones.es/esqui-y-snowboard/lanzadera-la-pinilla-2/)

Can anyone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742289/jquery-ui-date-picker-disabling-specific-dates

Comment: Pavlo, These don´t works for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date format you're using `dd-mm-yy` equates to 22-02-2014 not 22-02-14 in jQuery. You could either change the declaration of the array to:

```
var array = ["22-02-2014"];
```

or change the format used in formatDate to:

```
var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-y', date);
```

I'd suggest the first option as the second option would not allow 22-02-1914 to be selected.

A JSFiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AkJCy/)