# how to disable selected week days from the datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

in my project i'm saving the holidays from admin side and the value is storing like this in database table. `sunday,monday,friday` . I used the following code to extract them.

```
$da = array(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10);       
$holidays = explode(',', $data['dates']); 
for ($i = 0; $i < count($holidays); $i++) {
    switch($holidays[$i]) {
        case 'sunday':
            $da[$i] = 0;
            break;
        case 'monday':
            $da[$i] = 1;
            break;
        case 'tuesday':
            $da[$i] = 2;
            break;
        case 'wednesday':
            $da[$i] = 3;
            break;
        case 'thursday':
            $da[$i] = 4;
            break;
        case 'friday':        
            $da[$i] = 5;
            break;
        case 'saturday':
            $da[$i] = 6;
            break;
    }
}
```

And my script is :

```
 $(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: DisableMonday
    });
    });

function DisableMonday(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    var tooltipDate='holiday !';
    return [(day != <?php echo $da[0];?> && day != <?php echo $da[1];?> && day != <?php echo $da[2];?> && day != <?php echo $da[3];?> && day != <?php echo $da[4];?> && day != <?php echo $da[5];?> && day != <?php echo $da[6];?>),'',tooltipDate];
}
```

and html is :

```
<?php 
    if (Session::get('dates')){ 
        echo Form::text('date', Session::get('dates'), array('id'=> 'datepicker')); 
    } 
    else { 
        echo Form::text('date', '', array('id'=> 'datepicker'));
    }    
?>
```

The `var_dump` of `$da` for the db value sunday,monday,friday is :

```
array(7) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(1) [2]=> int(5) [3]=> int(10) [4]=> int(10) [5]=> int(10) [6]=> int(10) }
```

The output I'm getting is a normal calendar. no week days are disabled.
Anyone if found any mistakes in my code please guide me to correct it .

Comment: are there any console errors..??Check this http://jsfiddle.net/f9y3afhy/

Comment: @Outlooker : No dear.. only some icon missing error in that page is showing..no error related to datepicker is showing

Comment: Could you try replacing the return statement in DisableMonday function with `return [(day != 1 ),'',tooltipDate];`

Comment: @Outlooker : hi.. i've tried that.. it worked.. :( i know there is some mistakes in my code.. could please help me to find out that?

Comment: Could you try replacing the same return statement with `return [(day != <?php echo $da[0];?> ),'',tooltipDate];`

Comment: Remove the extra `});` after datepicker

Comment: I tested your code in my local and it is working fine ...

Comment: and `recheck` the value of $data['dates']

Comment: @Runcorn : Hi dear..sorry its not extra }); . i missed  `$(function() {` while pasting the coding in post

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery ui - date picker, disabling specific dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742289/jquery-ui-date-picker-disabling-specific-dates)

Comment: Hi i have updated my post with the dump of $da. it contains the value corresponding to sunday =0 , monday=1 , and friday =5

Comment: @Outlooker : it didn't worked :(

Comment: Check if the `$da` array is globally declared.

Comment: @Outlooker : oh..yeah.. that was the issue.. now its working.. thank you dear