# JQuery ui - date picker, Date Formating

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to impliment the same functionality as in this qeustion [JQuery ui - date picker, disabling specific dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742289/jquery-ui-date-picker-disabling-specific-dates) , the script working fine(see the code below), but the problem is I am getting Unavailable dates from database, so the dates has a leading zero, ie  `var unavailableDates = ["90-3-2012", "14-03-2012", "15-03-2012"];`
If I test with same dates without leading zero it works, but I want to with leading zero.

How can we format the dates, I am using the exact code from an answer for the above said quesiton , here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var unavailableDates = ["9-3-2012", "14-3-2012", "15-3-2012"];

    function unavailable(date) {
        dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
        if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
            return [true, ""];
        } else {
            return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
        }
    }

    $(function() {
        $("#iDate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
            beforeShowDay: unavailable
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use datepicker to [format date](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate) like

```js
var unavailableDates = ["09-03-2012", "14-03-2012", "15-03-2012", "15-07-2015"];

function unavailable(date) {
  var dmy = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
  console.log(dmy)
  if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
    return [true, ""];
  } else {
    return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
  }
}

$(function() {
  $("#iDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
    beforeShowDay: unavailable
  });

});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="iDate" />
```