# jQuery datepicker disable date and the following date as well

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Hi I have a issue with the jQuery datepicker.

Tried to search post but cannot get any solution yet.
I am trying to implement the jQuery datepicker to disable specific date with the below code. But instead of disable that specific dates, I need the following is also disable. Let, if I disable 20-01-2016, the 21-01-2016 will also automatic disabled.

Anyone can help please?

```
        var disabledDays = ["8-5-2016","8-25-2016"];

        function nationalDays(date) {
            var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
            for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
                if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,disabledDays) != -1 || new Date() > date) {
                    return [false];
                }
            }
            return [true];
        }

        function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date) {
            var noWeekend = jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
            return noWeekend[0] ? nationalDays(date) : noWeekend;
        }


        $( "#step3a" ).datepicker({
            showButtonPanel: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", 
            minDate: +2,
            beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays
        });
```

Comment: Please read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742289/jquery-ui-date-picker-disabling-specific-dates

Comment: Hi Vijay, yes the disabled date is added in the array. But how we can make also the date disable itself but also disabled the following 1 days.
Because I dont want to add the following date disabled by calling again it in the array.

Comment: So you want to enable that date when date picker open again, right?

Comment: Hi Vijay, not so. 
What I need is eg:, if we put the var disabledDays = ["8-5-2016","8-25-2016"];
the follow date for these 2 dates, "8-6-2016" and "8-26-2016" will be disabled too.

As what we need is when a specific date is disabled, it will disabled for 2 days always.

Comment: you need to disabled for 8-6-2016.17..... and so on right? If yes then please remove year from array e.g. var yourArray=['8-6','8-26']

Comment: Hi Vijay, thank you for your feedback. I think you got me wrong.
Basically, the thing we need is, example, if we set the disabledDate to be "12-01-2016", the next day for this disabled date "13-01-2016" will be auto disable too. It is not for entire year.

Comment: Hmm. Please see this http://jsfiddle.net/vijay_maheriya/f4e9ae3e/3/

Comment: Yes, thank you so much Vijay, your solution work perfectly!

Comment: Welcome and Vote comment because helpful to other user.Thanks