# How to disable click on month in calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

As you can see on the image I want to disable click on December 2017 (black box). How can I do this?

[image]

My javascript function for the calendar.

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    multidate: true,
    maxViewMode: 0,
    startDate: today,
})
```

Comment: See this old answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742289/jquery-ui-date-picker-disabling-specific-dates

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use [`changeMonth`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-changeMonth) option as following :

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  changeYear: true,
  changeMonth: false,
  multidate: true,
  maxViewMode: 0,
  startDate: new Date(),
});

$('#datepicker2').datepicker({
  changeYear: true,
  changeMonth: true,
  multidate: true,
  maxViewMode: 0,
  startDate: new Date(),
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 1%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="You can't change my month !" />
<input type="text" id="datepicker2" placeholder="You can change my month !" />
```