# How to block specific dates in a Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using date picker to pull a calendar on my store.

However, I am having issue with it.

I am trying to block specific dates and also have the calendar move to the next day after a certain time.

I try the following code

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#attrib-11-0").datepicker({minDate: new Date().getHours() >= 13 ? 1 : 0});

    //replace these with the id's of your datepickers
    $("#attrib-11-0").datepicker({

      beforeShowDay: function(date){          
         var disabledDays = ["10-2-2020", "11-2-2020","12-2-2020","13-2-2020","14-2-2020"];
         var day = date.getDay();
         var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('d-m-yy', date);
         var isDisabled = ($.inArray(string, disabledDays) != -1);

         //day != 0 disables all Sundays
         return [day != 0 && !isDisabled];

      }
    });
```

Unfortunately it is not working.

If I remove this, the dates are blocked properly. If I leave it in, the calendar goes to the next day after the specified time but the dates and Sunday are unblocked.

```
$("#attrib-11-0").datepicker({minDate: new Date().getHours() >= 13 ? 1 : 0});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQuery ui - date picker, disabling specific dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742289/jquery-ui-date-picker-disabling-specific-dates)

Answer (score 0):

please use `beforeShowDay` to do this

check this artical [disable-dates-in-datepicker](https://dzone.com/articles/disable-dates-in-datepicker)

```
var array = ["2020-03-14","2020-03-15","2020-03-16"]

$('input').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }
});
```