# Simple way to grey out holidays in datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I need to grey out or atleast highlight holidays. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Here is my code. Anyone got some ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#DatePickerStart').datepicker({
                beforeShowDay:
                    $.datepicker.noWeekends, dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy', minDate: '-2', firstDay: 1
            }, $.datepicker.regional["de"]).val();

            $('#DatePickerEnd').datepicker({
                beforeShowDay:
                    $.datepicker.noWeekends, dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy', minDate: '0', firstDay: 1
            }, $.datepicker.regional["de"]).val();
        });
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure there is a way to disable all of them. But you can make an array of the dates you want disabled (or better yet an easy to modify config file since they might change each year) and disable those one by one.. Prehaps this might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742289/jquery-ui-date-picker-disabling-specific-dates

Comment: @Eden Have you tested the solution

Comment: @Frenchy I have not tested it yet because my coworker has apparently found another way but thank you very much for the solution.I will test it out whenever I can.

Comment: so please dont forget to validate the answer to close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as say Landenne, you could use an array:

and the return function

```
return [true, 'holiday', 'tooltip1';  //enable
return [false, 'holiday', 'tooltip1'; //disable
```

if true, you could add css `holiday` and tooltip

```
  .ui-datepicker td.holiday a, .ui-datepicker td.holiday a:hover {
    background: grey;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
```

if false, you disable the date

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var holiDays = [ //YYYY,MM,DD
    [2021, 04, 01, 'test one date'], 
    [2021, 04, 14, 'test range', 2021, 04, 30],
    [2021, 12, 25, 'Christmas Day'],
    [2021, 07, 01, 'long holidays', 2021, 08, 31]
  ];
  
  holiDays = wrapDate(holiDays);

  $("#DatePickerStart").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: setHoliDays
  });

  // set holidays function which is configured in beforeShowDay
  function setHoliDays(date) {
    let dt = wrapDate(date);
    for (i = 0; i < holiDays.length; i++) {

      if (dt >= holiDays[i][0] && dt <= holiDays[i][1]) {

        return [true, 'holiday', holiDays[i][2]];
      }
    }
    return [true, ''];
  }

  function wrapDate(date) {
    if ($.isArray(date)) {// is holidays array?
      let ar = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < date.length; i++) {
        if (date[i].length < 5) { //only one date
          let ymd = date[i][0] * 10000 + date[i][1] * 100 + date[i][2];
          ar.push([ymd, ymd, date[i][3]]);
        } else { // range date
          let ymd1 = date[i][0] * 10000 + date[i][1] * 100 + date[i][2];
          let ymd2 = date[i][4] * 10000 + date[i][5] * 100 + date[i][6];
          ar.push([ymd1, ymd2, date[i][3]]);
        }
      }
      return ar;
    }
    // else format date to YYYYMMDD
    return date.getFullYear() * 10000 + (date.getMonth() + 1) * 100 + date.getDate();
  }

});
```

```css
.ui-datepicker .weekend .ui-state-default {
  background: #FEA;
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar {
  width: 100%;
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar>td>a {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.ui-datepicker td.holiday a, .ui-datepicker td.holiday a:hover {
  background: grey;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div class="Calendar" id="DatePickerStart">
</div>
```